# how to hide my Google translate API key？

Tags: php, javascript, translation, google-translate

I am using jquery translate which uses Google translate to provide the service. I am actually paying for the translation service. However, some websites just grabbed my API key (including code) and used it. In the end, I have to pay for them. Thus, I am wondering if there is a way to hide the key.

code:

```
<script language="javascript"> 

$.translate.load("API key");

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submit").click(function() {

    $.translate('text', 'en','es', {
            complete: function(translation){
             }

    });




})
```

Comment: An API key should only work in the domains it was created for

Comment: Yeah, if they grabbed your code including key and attempt to use it, it should fail for them.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, it is now working for them. I will check my api settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per Google's [API Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html):

> You can specify which domains are allowed to use your API key by
>   clicking the Edit allowed referers link in the Simple API Access
>   section of the API Access pane in the APIs Console.

Go to the [API Console](http://code.google.com/apis/console) and modify accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could restrict access to API based on IP or referrer.